# sylius or sonata or custom for subscription based application

Tags: symfony, subscription, sylius, multisite, sonata

We are going to build something like cratejoy.com, but don't want spend lot's of time building which is already builded before for developers.

I was going through sonata and sylius, but not sure if we can build subscription based model with one of them. If yes we can, then which would be best to use? or should we just build complete custom solution, because it involve b2b solution.

**What we will be building?**

Basically e-commerce software like any os-commerce shopping system, but the only difference is, we will be adding subscription on each product.

So let's say, if you order a product, we will ship it to you every month to your door step.

but we are building this as service, so many people can just create their site and start using our tools to start selling there products.

Comment: Apart from "subscription based model" (which is quite vague) and the reference to cratejoy.com (which doesn't really clarify anything), you don't mention anything about what it is you need... Maybe you should give us some detailed requirements?

Comment: ok I will add more desc :)

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer added description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be a little biased towards Sylius, as I work with it constantly - I've tried using Sonata bundles in projects before but failed in making use of them.

Reasons for using Sylius are that it's heavily decoupled and customizable, which is exactly what you want if you need an e-commerce solution that is not the conventional "add product to basket, pay for it once" model.

There are two approaches you can take to use Sylius: Either use the full stack application and customize it, which is the most common approach and better supported. The other approach is to install Sylius like a library rather than an application and build the application and frontend yourself, using Sylius classes and services when you need to (which is what I do).

Things to be careful when using Sylius are that it's still in beta, with breaking changes occurring between releases. Also the documentation is very incomplete or outdated (something I plan to help improve), with the exception of `Resource` and `ResourceBundle` - these packages are the most important part of Sylius and are therefore very well documented. For your project, I recommend the first option.

For subscriptions, areas of Sylius you want to look at configuring and extending are `OrderBundle`, `PricingBundle` and `PaymentBundle`. If you're very familiar with Symfony, this should be straightforward.

Comment: Is the project you are working on open source - anyway to see how you configured it? I'm currently trying to use sylius components/bundles within an existing system. // I find the config documentation lacking and each component I add requests another 3 components to be installed.. Im pretty much installing all of them at this point. // Should I have them all installed?

Comment: @mr12086 it will be a few weeks time as "nmarket". It was initially developed for a client but they went a different direction, and so I'm just in the process of white-labeling it and getting it in sync with the latest changes in Sylius - the most challenging part of Sylius-based development